# Way to create a dictionary while iterating through a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

this is my first question here so please excuse me for any formatting errors.

I have a dataframe that let's say looks like this

```
ID | Contact | First Name | Last Name
 1 |    A    |    Joe     |    Doe
 1 |    B    |    Jane    |    Doe
 2 |    C    |    Peter   |    Parker
 2 |    D    |    Iron    |    Man
```

And I want to iterate through the dataframe and create a dictionary so I get results such as:

```
{1:{A:[Joe, Doe]}, {B:[Jane, Doe]}, 2:{C:[Peter, Parker]},{D:[Iron, Man]}}
```

I'm using pandas to create the dataframe and I've been struggling with this for a while, maybe I'm too far down the rabbithole and the answer is rather easy or something different from what I've already tried.

I tried using a for loop to iterate through the contacts and then checking if the ID repeated and then grouping them together but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create a `Full Name` column then loop through groupby and specify what you want to do with the data:

```
df['Full Name'] = df[['First Name', 'Last Name']].agg(list, axis=1)

out = {i:d.set_index('Contact')['Full Name'].to_dict() 
          for i,d in df.groupby('ID')}
```

Output:

```
{1: {'A': ['Joe', 'Doe'], 'B': ['Jane', 'Doe']},
 2: {'C': ['Peter', 'Parker'], 'D': ['Iron', 'Man']}}
```

Comment: This works as intended, I had to use it with more columns not just 'First Name, Last Name' and it still worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since the ID seems to be one key for the rest of the informations from this ID, you can try this (which puts all the informations from the ID into a list):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,2,2], 'Contact': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'First Name': ['Joe', 'Jane', 'Peter', 'Iron'], 'Last Name': ['Doe', 'Doe', 'Parker', 'Man']})

res = {}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cur_id = row[0]
    cur_contact = row[1]
    cur_fname = row[2]
    cur_lname = row[3]

    if cur_id in res:
        res[cur_id].append({cur_contact: [cur_fname, cur_lname]})
    else:
        res[cur_id] = [{cur_contact: [cur_fname, cur_lname]}]

print(res)
```

output:

```
{1: [{'A': ['Joe', 'Doe']}, {'B': ['Jane', 'Doe']}],
 2: [{'C': ['Peter', 'Parker']}, {'D': ['Iron', 'Man']}]}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This will be helpful in this scenario, but since in my real case I'm using way more columns this method is not as effective since it will involve a lot of lines of code.

Still taking notes of this approach for future scenarios! Again, thank you for your help